# How can I get out of Corel Desert?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

While roaming around the overworld, I found myself into the Corel Desert, an area that loops in all directions.

How can I get out?

Answer (score 1):

Reach the top of the area and "exit" north, then south, then north, then south... until a scene happens, offering you to return to the world map.

Comment: After enough 'area' changes the exit scene happens every time, however your method is probably the fastest way.